# SQL greater than but the least

Tags: sql, sqlite

let this be my table:

```
id    timestamp
1     100
2     102
3     102
4     104
```

I want to query SQLite the record with the timestamp greater than 100 stopping when I find one but returning all with that value.

So in the case of timestamp > 100: 2 and 3 (timestamp 102). Not 4 because is 104 ( > 102)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE timestamp = 
    (SELECT timestamp FROM your_table 
          WHERE timestamp > 100 ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1);
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE timestamp = 
    (SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM your_table WHERE timestamp > 100)
```

In both cases you're using an internal `SELECT` statement to determine what timestamp value you're searching for.

I suspect the first version, while a little more complicated to write, will perform better under some indexing situations since it can, in theory, check only a single row to get that timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE timestamp = (
SELECT min(timestamp)
  FROM tbl
 WHERE timestamp > 100
)
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bb3ea/2) to see the above code in action, and to prove it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from mytable where timestamp =
(  -- second least timestamp
  select min(timestamp) from mytable where timestamp > 
  ( -- least timestamp
    select min(timestamp) from mytable
  )
);
```